# Definition of Strongly Shattering

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I am familiar with what it means for a collection $\mathcal{F}\subseteq 2^{[n]}$ to shatter a set $S$, $$2^{S} = \{F \cap S: F\in \mathcal{F}\}.$$

I'm reading a paper and they introduce the notion of strongly shattering a set $S$. If there exists an $I\subseteq [n]\backslash F$ such that $$2^F + I = \{H\cup I: H\subseteq F\}\subseteq \mathcal{F}.$$

This definition does not appear to follow directly from the definition of shattering a set. I would appreciate if someone could explain this definition in plain English so that I could better understand it.

It is clear to me that if $2^F \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ then $\mathcal{F}$ shatters $F$, although this is not the only way in which $\mathcal{F}$ can shatter $F$. Is the idea that $\mathcal{F}$ shatters $F$ and *more*?

Comment: I'm thinking that strongly shattering is a specific way in which a set can be shattered, and it asks that $\mathcal{F}$ is not equal to the powerset of the set you shatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "$\mathcal F$ shatters $S$" can be stated as "For all subsets $A \subseteq S$, there is a set $B$ disjoint from $S$ such that $A \cup B \in \mathcal F$".

The statement "$\mathcal F$ strongly shatters $S$" can be stated as "There is a set $B$ disjoint from $S$ such that for all subsets $A \subseteq S$, $A \cup B \in \mathcal F$".

The only difference is that we must use the same $B$ for every $A$. This is a stronger condition: if $\mathcal F$ strongly shatters $S$, then $\mathcal F$ shatters $S$, but the reverse is not necessarily true.

For example:

- to shatter $\{1,2\}$, $\mathcal F$ might contain the sets $\{3,4,5\}$ (for $\emptyset \subseteq \{1,2\}$), $\{1, 6\}$ (for $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$),  $\{2,4,8\}$ (for $\{2\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$) and $\{1,2,3\}$ (for $\{1,2\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$).
- to strongly shatter $\{1,2\}$, $\mathcal F$ might contain all the sets $\{3,5\}$, $\{1,3,5\}$, $\{2,3,5\}$, and $\{1,2,3,5\}$.

Comment: I think I understand now. I never thought of shattering in terms of unions before, only in terms of intersections, which is possibly part of what confused me. It seems as though the only difference is the order in which the quantifiers appear, sort of like the difference between pointwise and uniform convergence.

Comment: @misha.fish I'm not entirely certain why in your definition of $\mathcal{F}$ shatters $S$ we need to ask that $B$ is disjoint from $S$. I know that for all $A \subseteq S$ there is some $F \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A=F \cap S$, so upon rearranging, wouldn't this $B$ have to be related to $S$ somehow?

Comment: If we have $A = F \cap S$, then we can write $F$ as $(F \cap S) \cup (F - S)$, where $F \cap S$ is just $A$ and $F-S$ is what we define to be $B$. If we don't ask for $B$ to be disjoint from $S$, then it's possible we get a set whose intersection with $S$ is not $A$.